# outofmemory when sliding on imageswitcher

Tags: android

is there any way to disable the slide scrolling on the imageswitcher
my app has over 400 images
and if i click through the imageswitcher everything works
but when i slide scroll after a while it crashes with outofmemory error

so is there anyway to disable the feature

```
package com.quartergames.owen.MyRoadTrip;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class ImageSwitcherView extends Activity implements ViewFactory {
    Integer pics[] = { R.drawable.image000, R.drawable.image001,
            R.drawable.image002, R.drawable.image003, R.drawable.image004,
            R.drawable.image005, R.drawable.image006, R.drawable.image007,
            R.drawable.image008, R.drawable.image009, R.drawable.image010,
            R.drawable.image011, R.drawable.image012, R.drawable.image013,
            R.drawable.image014, R.drawable.image015, R.drawable.image016,
            R.drawable.image017, R.drawable.image018, R.drawable.image019,
            R.drawable.image020, R.drawable.image021, R.drawable.image022,
            R.drawable.image023, R.drawable.image024, R.drawable.image025,
            R.drawable.image026, R.drawable.image027, R.drawable.image028,
            R.drawable.image029, R.drawable.image030, R.drawable.image031,
            R.drawable.image032, R.drawable.image033, R.drawable.image034,
            R.drawable.image035, R.drawable.image036, R.drawable.image037,
            R.drawable.image038, R.drawable.image039, R.drawable.image040,
            R.drawable.image041, R.drawable.image042, R.drawable.image043,
            R.drawable.image044, R.drawable.image045, R.drawable.image046,
            R.drawable.image047, R.drawable.image048, R.drawable.image049,
            R.drawable.image050, R.drawable.image051, R.drawable.image052,
            R.drawable.image053, R.drawable.image054, R.drawable.image055,
            R.drawable.image056, R.drawable.image057, R.drawable.image058,
            R.drawable.image059, R.drawable.image060, R.drawable.image061,
            R.drawable.image062, R.drawable.image063, R.drawable.image064,
            R.drawable.image065, R.drawable.image066, R.drawable.image067,
            R.drawable.image068, R.drawable.image069, R.drawable.image070,
            R.drawable.image071, R.drawable.image072, R.drawable.image073,
            R.drawable.image074, R.drawable.image075, R.drawable.image076,
            R.drawable.image077, R.drawable.image078, R.drawable.image079,
            R.drawable.image080, R.drawable.image081, R.drawable.image082,
            R.drawable.image083, R.drawable.image084, R.drawable.image085,
            R.drawable.image086, R.drawable.image087, R.drawable.image088,
            R.drawable.image089, R.drawable.image090, R.drawable.image091,
            R.drawable.image092, R.drawable.image093, R.drawable.image094,
            R.drawable.image095, R.drawable.image096, R.drawable.image097,
            R.drawable.image098, R.drawable.image099, R.drawable.image100,
            R.drawable.image101, R.drawable.image102, R.drawable.image103,
            R.drawable.image104, R.drawable.image105, R.drawable.image106,
            R.drawable.image107, R.drawable.image108, R.drawable.image109,
            R.drawable.image110, R.drawable.image111, R.drawable.image112,
            R.drawable.image113, R.drawable.image114, R.drawable.image115,
            R.drawable.image116, R.drawable.image117, R.drawable.image118,
            R.drawable.image119, R.drawable.image120, R.drawable.image121,
            R.drawable.image122, R.drawable.image123, R.drawable.image124,
            R.drawable.image125, R.drawable.image126, R.drawable.image127,
            R.drawable.image128, R.drawable.image129, R.drawable.image130,
            R.drawable.image131, R.drawable.image132, R.drawable.image133,
            R.drawable.image134, R.drawable.image135, R.drawable.image136,
            R.drawable.image137, R.drawable.image138, R.drawable.image139,
            R.drawable.image140, R.drawable.image141, R.drawable.image142,
            R.drawable.image143, R.drawable.image144, R.drawable.image145,
            R.drawable.image146, R.drawable.image147, R.drawable.image148,
            R.drawable.image149, R.drawable.image150, R.drawable.image151,
            R.drawable.image152, R.drawable.image153, R.drawable.image154,
            R.drawable.image155, R.drawable.image156, R.drawable.image157,
            R.drawable.image158, R.drawable.image159, R.drawable.image160,
            R.drawable.image161, R.drawable.image162, R.drawable.image163,
            R.drawable.image164, R.drawable.image165, R.drawable.image166,
            R.drawable.image167, R.drawable.image168, R.drawable.image169,
            R.drawable.image170, R.drawable.image171, R.drawable.image172,
            R.drawable.image173, R.drawable.image174, R.drawable.image175,
            R.drawable.image176, R.drawable.image177, R.drawable.image178,
            R.drawable.image179, R.drawable.image180, R.drawable.image181,
            R.drawable.image182, R.drawable.image183, R.drawable.image184,
            R.drawable.image185, R.drawable.image186, R.drawable.image187,
            R.drawable.image188, R.drawable.image189, R.drawable.image190,
            R.drawable.image191, R.drawable.image192, R.drawable.image193,
            R.drawable.image194, R.drawable.image195, R.drawable.image196,
            R.drawable.image197, R.drawable.image198, R.drawable.image199,
            R.drawable.image200, R.drawable.image221, R.drawable.image222,
            R.drawable.image223, R.drawable.image224, R.drawable.image225,
            R.drawable.image226, R.drawable.image227, R.drawable.image228,
            R.drawable.image229, R.drawable.image210, R.drawable.image211,
            R.drawable.image212, R.drawable.image213, R.drawable.image214,
            R.drawable.image215, R.drawable.image216, R.drawable.image217,
            R.drawable.image218, R.drawable.image219, R.drawable.image220,
            R.drawable.image221, R.drawable.image222, R.drawable.image223,
            R.drawable.image224, R.drawable.image225, R.drawable.image226,
            R.drawable.image227, R.drawable.image228, R.drawable.image229,
            R.drawable.image230, R.drawable.image231, R.drawable.image232,
            R.drawable.image233, R.drawable.image234, R.drawable.image235,
            R.drawable.image236, R.drawable.image237, R.drawable.image238,
            R.drawable.image239, R.drawable.image240, R.drawable.image241,
            R.drawable.image242, R.drawable.image243, R.drawable.image244,
            R.drawable.image245, R.drawable.image246, R.drawable.image247,
            R.drawable.image248, R.drawable.image249, R.drawable.image250,
            R.drawable.image251, R.drawable.image252, R.drawable.image253,
            R.drawable.image254, R.drawable.image255, R.drawable.image256,
            R.drawable.image257, R.drawable.image258, R.drawable.image259,
            R.drawable.image260, R.drawable.image261, R.drawable.image262,
            R.drawable.image263, R.drawable.image264, R.drawable.image265,
            R.drawable.image266, R.drawable.image267, R.drawable.image268,
            R.drawable.image269, R.drawable.image270, R.drawable.image271,
            R.drawable.image272, R.drawable.image273, R.drawable.image274,
            R.drawable.image275, R.drawable.image276, R.drawable.image277,
            R.drawable.image278, R.drawable.image279, R.drawable.image280,
            R.drawable.image281, R.drawable.image282, R.drawable.image283,
            R.drawable.image284, R.drawable.image285, R.drawable.image286,
            R.drawable.image287, R.drawable.image288, R.drawable.image289,
            R.drawable.image290, R.drawable.image291, R.drawable.image292,
            R.drawable.image293, R.drawable.image294, R.drawable.image295,
            R.drawable.image296, R.drawable.image297, R.drawable.image298,
            R.drawable.image299, R.drawable.image300, R.drawable.image301,
            R.drawable.image302, R.drawable.image303, R.drawable.image304,
            R.drawable.image305, R.drawable.image306, R.drawable.image307,
            R.drawable.image308, R.drawable.image309, R.drawable.image310,
            R.drawable.image311, R.drawable.image312, R.drawable.image313,
            R.drawable.image314, R.drawable.image315, R.drawable.image316,
            R.drawable.image317, R.drawable.image318, R.drawable.image319,
            R.drawable.image320, R.drawable.image321, R.drawable.image322,
            R.drawable.image323, R.drawable.image324, R.drawable.image325,
            R.drawable.image326, R.drawable.image327, R.drawable.image328,
            R.drawable.image329, R.drawable.image330, R.drawable.image331,
            R.drawable.image332, R.drawable.image333, R.drawable.image334,
            R.drawable.image335, R.drawable.image336, R.drawable.image337,
            R.drawable.image338, R.drawable.image339, R.drawable.image340,
            R.drawable.image341, R.drawable.image342, R.drawable.image343,
            R.drawable.image344, R.drawable.image345, R.drawable.image346,
            R.drawable.image347, R.drawable.image348, R.drawable.image349,
            R.drawable.image350, R.drawable.image351, R.drawable.image352,
            R.drawable.image353, R.drawable.image354, R.drawable.image355,
            R.drawable.image356, R.drawable.image357, R.drawable.image358,
            R.drawable.image359, R.drawable.image360, R.drawable.image361,
            R.drawable.image362, R.drawable.image363, R.drawable.image364,
            R.drawable.image365, R.drawable.image366, R.drawable.image367,
            R.drawable.image368, R.drawable.image369, R.drawable.image370,
            R.drawable.image371, R.drawable.image372, R.drawable.image373,
            R.drawable.image374, R.drawable.image375, R.drawable.image376,
            R.drawable.image377, R.drawable.image378, R.drawable.image379,
            R.drawable.image380, R.drawable.image381, R.drawable.image382,
            R.drawable.image383, R.drawable.image384, R.drawable.image385,
            R.drawable.image386, R.drawable.image387, R.drawable.image388,
            R.drawable.image389, R.drawable.image390, R.drawable.image391,
            R.drawable.image392, R.drawable.image393, R.drawable.image394,
            R.drawable.image395, R.drawable.image396, R.drawable.image397,
            R.drawable.image398, R.drawable.image399, R.drawable.image400,
            R.drawable.image401, R.drawable.image402, R.drawable.image403,
            R.drawable.image404, R.drawable.image405 };

    ImageSwitcher iSwitcher;
    private int currentlySelectedPic = 0;
    private int currentlySelectedIndex = 0;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Gallery gallery;
    SqlLiteHelper slHelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galleryview);
        slHelper = new SqlLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (currentlySelectedIndex > 0){
        }else{

        currentlySelectedIndex = extras.getInt("bookmark");
        Log.e("Test",String.valueOf(currentlySelectedIndex));

        }


        iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher01);
        iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setSelection(currentlySelectedIndex);
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                currentlySelectedPic = pics[arg2];
                currentlySelectedIndex = arg2;
                iSwitcher.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("bookmark", gallery.getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor.commit();
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
            iView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);

            iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            return iView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
        iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        iView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        iView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);

        iView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ImageSwitcherView.this,
                        imageView.class);
                currentlySelectedPic = pics[currentlySelectedIndex];
                myIntent.putExtra("resID", currentlySelectedPic);
                myIntent.putExtra("index", currentlySelectedIndex);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
            }
        });

        return iView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        currentlySelectedIndex = data.getIntExtra("bookmark", 0);
        gallery.setSelection(currentlySelectedIndex);
        iSwitcher.setImageResource(pics[currentlySelectedIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i simplified the app and cut out the imageswitcher.  once doing this i noticed that it was messing up at the same location.  so i looked at the images for that location.  they where the largest images (600kb, 400kb) also these images had very high dimensions (1600,1400).  changeing these images to 800x600 reduced the size and fixed the problem. i think it was the dimensions more then the size.  because one of the images that had a problem was around 300kb (which is similar to other images that dont have problems).  in short fixing the dimensions on the image fixed the problem.

Comment: you could also create thumbnails of the images instead of using the full size images.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would strongly advise to check the View argument in `getView` (arg1 in your code) and use that instead of creating a new ImageView to properly recycle the old one. You could even try to `dispose` the previous bitmap if that's possible.
2. Is this in the debugger? Using the debugger is known to leak memory when you deal with bitmaps (in certain circumstances).
3. "Disable the feature"? What feature?
4. You could also consider some sort of LRU cache for bitmaps and dispose of the oldest one, although that's probably more involved than you have to be here.

Side note: Any reason you're creating an Integer array rather than an int array?

Comment: this is on the emulator but also my phone.  "Disable the feature" i meant for the slide motion of imageswitcher.  like i said the app works fine as long as you dont run your finger across the gallery to slide it.  if you were to select the next picture (picture for picture) it works fine.  (1) i will look into this.    THANKS

Comment: The slide motion is not the culprit here. You must be leaking memory. How big are those images?

Comment: the total apk is 23mb each image is around 40kb.   but the errors and crashing only happen on slide as far as i can tell

Comment: I'd definitely try what I put under item 1. Should take you 5 minutes.

Comment: yes im looking into that now.  the only thing is that the imageview doesnt update when scrolled its only when its clicked.  so if i open the app to this class.  and the gallery/imageswitcher populate, at this point imageview isnt even loaded.  and at this point i can crash the app with slideing the gallery/imageswitcher

Comment: I removed the imageswitcher and makeView.  but the gallery still had problems.  i looked deeper at where it was having problems.  it seems like the culprit was 3 particular images.  the images had a size of around 600kb and dimensions of 1600x1400.   (ill answer the question in 8 hours when it lets me)